# bootstrap popup modal overlapping page header

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a webpage that has a header that is always on top of everything else. If I add a bootstrap modal to popup, it has a grey area that covers the header.

I've tried setting the `z-index`  for both my red background header element, and my modal-popup element, but it just results in the modal grey box being overtop my red navbar which I am trying to avoid.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/u03f1zyo/21/

Comment: Have you tried adding css that positions the gray piece of the modal under the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a modal pop up, it's created a div element on the top levels of the DOM, I went through a similar problem and setting the z-index like that solved it:

`.modal-backdrop.show { z-index: 1000 !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Your Header has default position which is
position: static;

Change it to:

CSS

```
header{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1041;
}
```

This will fix your issue. If you want to make your header sticky in future. position: fixed will also work. You should avoid touching Modal box z-index and instead change z-index of components on case by case basis.